# Hard Drive Won't Boot After OS Install

Tags: hard-drive, boot, xubuntu

This is my step by step process on a **Dell Inspiron 6000** with a brand new 320 HD:

- Turn on Laptop
- Insert Xubuntu 9.1 disc
- Boot to CD-rom
- After boot has finished, I install and instance of Xubuntu on the machine
- After install (without any errors), I reboot the the machine
- On reboot, the BIOS claims to be unable to read from device

What could this be? *(Feel free to ask for more information to perform a proper diagnosis)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you or the installer messed up (accidentally). Just try the installation again.

- Did you let the installer install
  grub in the MBR? (it'll ask you at
  the end of the installation).
- Did you try another Linux dristo
  (Ubuntu or a newer Xubuntu?).
- If everythin fails (maybe check this first): Are you SURE that it's the BIOS telling you it's unable to read from the device, not the boot loader or the OS?

Comment: Grub error 18. But I think I figured it out; I was reading somewhere about the BIOS not being able to read such a large hard drive.  When I went into the BIo and read the sys info, it only said the HD was 137 GB. So what I did was make a boot partition that was 80 gigs and left the rest well alone and it installed just fine.

Comment: Sounds like the Problem is solved!

What i would do in this case: Make a /boot partition that's only 256 MB in size and add the rest of the partition to /.

The only files that will be installed on /boot will be the 2nd stage of the bootloader - which will be loaded by the 1st stage in the MBR - which will be loaded by the BIOS) your kernel (ca. 15 MB on a fairly modern system) and a few other files needed to boot.

That way your Bios won't complain about your boot device (/boot) being to big and your root device (which contains /home, i figure?) will be in one piece and almost 320GBs.